# Getting SQL parameter error but the parameter is supplied - Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

```
public class SeedRepository<TEntity>  where TEntity : class
{
    public async Task Seed(IDbContextFactory<PropertyServantContext> contextFactory, List<TEntity> data)
    {
        string recordName = typeof(TEntity).Name;
        Log.Logger.Information("Seeding {0}", recordName);

        using (var ctx = contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
        {
            if (await ctx.Set<TEntity>().AnyAsync()) return;

            try
            {
                ctx.Database.OpenConnection();
                var result = ctx.Set<TEntity>().FromSql($"SET IDENTITY_INSERT {recordName} ON;");

                foreach (TEntity record in data)
                {
                    ctx.Set<TEntity>().Add(record);
                }

                ctx.SaveChanges();

                result = ctx.Set<TEntity>().FromSql($"SET IDENTITY_INSERT {recordName} OFF;");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Logger.Error(ex.ToString());
                throw;
            }
            finally 
            { 
                ctx.Database.CloseConnection(); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The statement

```
var result = ctx.Set<TEntity>().FromSql($"SET IDENTITY_INSERT {recordName} ON;");
```

causes an error

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException
> HResult=0x80131500
> An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
>
> Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational
>
> StackTrace:
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.Consume(RelationalDataReader reader)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Update.Internal.SqlServerModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IList`1 entries)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IList`1 entriesToSave) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.<>c.<SaveChanges>b__107_0(DbContext _, ValueTuple`2 t)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges()
> at PropertyServant.Data.PropertyServantContext.SaveChanges() in C:\Development\Git\PropertyServant\Property Servant API\PropertyServant.Data\PropertyServantContext.cs:line 51
> at PropertyServant.Data.Seeding.SeedRepository`1.d__0.MoveNext() in C:\Development\Git\PropertyServant\Property Servant API\PropertyServant.Data\Seeding\SeedRepository.cs:line 27
>
> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
> [External Code]
>
> Inner Exception 1:
> SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'AccountRule' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

The SET IDENTITY_INSERT command is not executing. If I replace the {recordName} with the name of the table then it runs correctly. Yes, recordName and table name are one in the same.

Comment: `FromSql` makes parameterization. It wraps the supplied value in a DbParameter. Try `FromSqlRaw` instead. More info in docs: [SQL Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries).

Comment: Moreover, you should use `ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw` method to execute a query that does not return any data.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, I was using ExecuteSql but was getting an error. Your suggestion to use ExecuteSqlRaw did the trick Thanks!

Comment: @GertArnold, I don't like the idea of having my seeding inside a migration. This works for the team and me.